# Replace all quotes that are not in html-tags

Tags: php, html, regex, replace

currently i am replacing all my quotes inside a text with special quotes. 
But how can i change my regex that only quotes inside the text will be replaced and not the ones who are used in html tags.

```
$text = preg_replace('/"(?=\w)/', "&raquo;", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)"/', "&laquo;", $text);
```

I am not that fit in regular expressions. The problem is that i need to replace the starting quotes with another symbol than ending quotes.

If you do need more information, say so.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Test Case

```
<p>This is a "wonderful long text". At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
```

The expected output should be:

```
<p>This is a &raquo;wonderful long text&laquo;. At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
```

Right now it is like this:

```
<p>This is a &raquo;wonderful long text&laquo;. At least it should be. Here we have a <a href=&raquo;http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com&laquo; target=&raquo;_blank&laquo;>link</a>.</p>
```

**EDIT 2**

Thx for the answer of Kamehameha i've added the following code to my script:

`$text = preg_replace("/\"([^<>]*?)\"(?=[^>]+?<)/", "&raquo;\1&laquo;", $text);`

What worked great in the regex tester does not replace anything. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: some test cases and how the output should be?

Comment: Safe, slow and obvious approach: throw into a HTML/XML parsing library and manipulate text nodes?

Comment: @AmitJoki: I've added an example!

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Thx for the input. I thought about it myself, but i really hope that there is a better regex method!

Comment: What happens when you have this situation `<tag> Hello " world <tag> wide " "The end" <tag>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This regex works for the given strings.

```
Search for   - "([^<>]*?)"(?=[^>]*?<)
Replace with - &raquo;\1&laquo;
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/uD4tK6)
Testing it -

```
INPUT - 
<p>This is a "wonderful long text". "Another wonderful ong text" At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>

OUTPUT - 
<p>This is a &raquo;wonderful long text&laquo;. &raquo;Another wonderful ong text&laquo; At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>
```

**EDIT 1-**
Executing this in PHP -

```
$str = '<p>This is a "wonderful long text". "Another wonderful ong text" At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>';
var_dump(preg_replace('/"([^<>]*?)"(?=[^>]*?<)/', '&raquo;\1&laquo', $str));
```

It's output -

```
/** OUTPUT **/
string '<p>This is a &raquo;wonderful long text&laquo. &raquo;Another wonderful ong text&laquo At least it should be. Here we have a <a href="http://wwww.site-to-nowhere.com" target="_blank">link</a>.</p>' (length=196)
```

**EDIT 2-**
You have executed the `preg_replace` function properly, but in the replacement string, you have used \1 inside the Double quotes(""). Doing so, you are escaping the 1 itself and that won't be replaced.
To make it more clear, try this and see what happens -

```
echo '&raquo;\1&laquo;';
echo "&raquo;\1&laquo;";
```

The second \1 should not be visible.
So the solution would be one of these -

```
preg_replace('/"([^<>]*?)"(?=[^>]*?<)/', '&raquo;\1&laquo;', $str)
preg_replace("/\"([^<>]*?)\"(?=[^>]*?<)/", "&raquo;\\1&laquo;", $str)
preg_replace("/\"([^<>]*?)\"(?=[^>]*?<)/", "&raquo;$1&laquo;", $str)
```

Read the Replacement section in [this page](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) for more clarity.

**EDIT 3-**
A regex that covers text which might not be enclosed within tags-

```
\"([^<>]*?)\"(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/xT0vZ1)

Comment: Your regexp is working absolutely great. Thx for that. But if i use it in php it won't replace anything. I added my new php code to my question. Can you have a look what i did wrong? This would be great!

Comment: @TobiasKun Sure gimme a min.

Comment: I do not understand why it is not working for me :( Can you try it with the content here: http://pastebin.com/yZrtXJ6n

Comment: @TobiasKun You had a problem with using quotes. Check Edit 2

Comment: @TobiasKun Tried your text from pastebin. It's working with the solution that I've provided.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found my error. Sometimes i have texts, that are not surrounded by html tags. Can i change the regexp so the text will work? If not, that's fine too. I could develop a method where i can assure that there is html around.

Comment: @TobiasKun Check the edit. I've added a new regex. It seems to work properly, but that being said, it's always a good idea if all the content are enclosed within HTML tags. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Could also use a negative lookahead:

```
(?![^<]*>)"([^"]+)"
```

Replace with: `&raquo;\1&laquo;`

Comment: This is even more amazing!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, there is a simple PHP solution that was not mentioned and that efficiently skips over all the `<a...</a>` tags.

Search: `<a.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|"([^"]*)"`

Replace: `&raquo;\1&laquo;`

In the [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jT9uY0), look at the Substitutions at the bottom.

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)
```

This will match non html strings.

And then do your regex on the resultant string

Comment: Great thx. But i am not really sure, how i can use it. Because at the end i need the whole text (incl. html tags) with replaced quotes.