# Replace double quotes in HTML avoiding tags

Tags: html, regex

My problem is the same of this request: [Replace all quotes that are not in html-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589725/replace-all-quotes-that-are-not-in-html-tags).

Howeaver, the solution provided to that request not works for all cases. Example: In this HTML fragment the first quoted text is matched, but the second is not. Howeaver the quotes aren't into a tag.

`<p>This quote is matched: "Hello, I'm a quote". <strong>But this it not: <i>"<strong>I'm also a quite :(</strong>"</i>.</p>`

See my demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tA0xV1

EDIT: The HTML is strictly validated.

Comment: So, you want to match quotes avoiding tags, but allow tags in the quotes??

Comment: This one needs counting brackets, which is impossible with regular expressions. What language are you writing in?

Comment: **1**. Questions should be stand alone, please explain briefly what you want to do (and link to the other question if you want, but as an illustration only) **2** As the [tag:regex] tag description suggests, please indicate which language you're using.

Comment: Also, you have a bug in your XML. One of `<strong>` tags is not closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer to myself, this regex works fine for my purposal, ensuring that first double quotes aren't preceded by `=` character:

`/(?![^<]*>)"(.*?)(?<!=)"(?!>)/g`

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/vT1eZ8

Comment: do not ever never use Regex for html, as html is not regular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I forgot to specify that HTML is stricly validated. In the meantime I've refined the regex to skip tags attributes quotes after the opening quote and before the closing quote.

Comment: It doesn't matter if HTML is validated or not. There's a Chomsky hierarchy of grammars. Regular expression is the least powerful of them. HTML needs a context-free grammar, and that's strictly more powerful than regular expressions. You cannot write a regex for your task.

Comment: I need a regex, not other ways sorry

Comment: @FedericoLiva I wouldn't use this, it's too easy to break. For example, use this perfectly valid HTML code as a test string: `"<a href="#" title="Test">Test</a>"`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this.

```
// your source (X)HTML
$data = '<p class="test"> This quote is matched: "Hello, I\'m a quote". But this it not: <i> </i> <i>"<strong>I\'m also a quite :(</strong>"</i>.</p>';

$r = new XMLReader;
$w = new XMLWriter;

$r->xml($data, 'UTF-8');
$w->openMemory();
$w->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// for each node
while ($r->read()) {
    // depending on node type
    switch ($r->nodeType) {
        // if it's tag opening
        case XMLReader::ELEMENT:
            // write it "as is"
            $w->startElement($r->name);
            if ($r->moveToFirstAttribute()) {
                do {
                    $w->startAttribute($r->name);
                    $w->text($r->value);
                    $w->endAttribute();
                } while ($r->moveToNextAttribute());
            }
            break;
            // if it's </tag>, output "as is"
        case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT:
            $w->endElement();
            break;
        // if it's a plain text
        case XMLReader::TEXT:
        case XMLReader::SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE:
            // replace quotes
            $w->text(str_replace('"', '%QUOTE%', $r->value));
            break;
        // there're quite a lot of node types
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown node type: " . $r->nodeType);
    }
}

// output the transformed XML    
$w->endDocument();
echo $w->outputMemory(TRUE);
```

Consult [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.xmlreader.php) and [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php) docs for further info. [Live version here.](http://ideone.com/kgEXdG)

Comment: It works thanks. Can I do this with a regular expression?

Comment: As I said earlier, "This one needs counting brackets, which is impossible with regular expressions". BTW Consider accepting an answer.

Comment: Check my answer, I've found a way using only a regex

Comment: do not ever never use Regex for html, as html is not regular